# Can you help me fixing this Slider code in ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, text, slider

I got a dynamic Textfield called txt_nOpp setted to 1,  I also got a slider, called Slider1, The slider can only assume values betweed 1 and 6. While the user sets slider value, the text should change.
I've implemented this code:

```
Slider1.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, slHandler); 
function slHandler(e:SliderEvent):void{
    txt_nOpp.text = String(e.value);
}
```

Flash doesn't return any error, but the slider/text works only at value 1, the other values of the slider make the text disappear... What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**SliderEvent.CHANGE** only updates when you release the slider, so try

```
Slider1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, function()
                         {
                            txt_nOpp.text = Slider1.value.toString(); 
                         });
```

instead.

Comment: I traced the values of txt_nOpp.text and Slider1.value.toString();  they are ok, the problem is to display it...

Comment: @user3161756 Right, you have to embed fonts, or use device fonts :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, it was an anti aliasing problem, just set it as device font and now works